# Beta-function integrand basis for function space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, integral-transforms

A problem I am trying to tackle seems like it could be significantly simplified if it were possible to choose a basis for the relevant function space as something like:

$$
\mathcal{B}_\mathrm{B} = 
\left\{
x^\alpha (1-x)^\beta \; : \; \alpha \in \mathbf{R}, \, \beta \in \mathbf{R}\setminus\mathbf{N}
\right\}
$$

or some variation of the above.  I have chosen the restriction on $\beta$ to remove the obvious linear-dependence relation otherwise.

I know the literature is full of various bases for different function spaces, e.g. arising from Sturm-Liouville problems, but don't recall seeing anything like this and couldn't find it in the references I consulted.

Does a basis of this form exist in the literature, does it have a name I should be aware of, and is there an integral kernel with respect to which these functions are orthogonal/orthonormal?

If not, is there an easy way to try to find one?

Comment: What basis? I mean, Schauder, Banach, Hilbert? The Beta distributions only exist (are integrable) in some ranges of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, no? And obviously, on smaller ranges they are in $\mathscr{L}^2.$

Comment: Yes, for integrability I would want further restrictions on the parameters. In terms of what kind of basis, I'm really thinking in terms of Sturm-Liouville theory, so this would be an eigenbasis for the (Hilbert?) subspace of solutions to some self-adjoint differential operator with given boundary conditions on $[0,1]$, should one exist or be easily identifiable. But any other context in which these are used as basis functions would likely also be of interest.

Comment: Frankly, I only know the Beta functions through probability theory. They are a parametrised family of functions that are perfect for fitting empirical distributions of data with a finite domain (e.g. human height).

Comment: Right, and that's roughly the idea that I'm hoping to use, except to describe a function, ideally by projecting out coefficients of each $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ with some kind of integral inner product with respect to which $(f_{\alpha,\beta}, f_{\alpha',\beta'}) = \delta_{\alpha\alpha'} \delta_{\beta \beta'}$ or similar.  This would follow from Sturm-Liouville theory if a suitable family of S-L DEs could be found for which the $f_{\alpha \beta}$ were eigenfunctions.  Perhaps someone has encountered this before, or perhaps I need to work on it for a bit myself!